# Problem with color, symbols and upper bar using airline with Vim in terminal

Tags: terminal, statusline, plugin-airline

I noticed 3 problems with my Vim terminal setup on Ubuntu which can be illustrated by the following picture of my current Vim. I get the same look with a lot of airline-themes (e.g. molokai, jellybeans, dark, etc.)
[image: current Vim]

- The first problem is that I'd like to have colors with my status bar which are clearly not appearing.
- Also I don't know if the symbols of the status bar are correct, because the arrows do not look like the ones shown below.
  [image]
- Finally the upper bar indicating the buffers or the tabs clearly do not look like mine.

Also, here are some potentially useful informations

- I installed the powerline patched Mac OS font Monaco. This helped me to replace some weird symbols and get the ones shown above.
- The only airline theme that was different was base16.
- I tried changing the Vim colorscheme to different ones, but it didn't solve anything.

Finally here is a copy of my .vimrc

```
set encoding=utf8

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git'
Plugin 'https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git'
Plugin 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround.git'
Plugin 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors.git'

Plugin 'dkprice/vim-easygrep'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'

" Optional:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
syntax on

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

"highlight Pmenu ctermfg=15 ctermbg=4 guifg=#ffffff guibg=#0000ff

let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 1
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_highlighting = 0
set number
set autochdir
set ruler
set ts=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set cursorline
set showmatch
set ignorecase
set showcmd
set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:·
" set timeoutlen = 200
set nofoldenable
set wildmode=full
set laststatus=2
set completeopt-=preview

map <Tab> <C-W>W
nnoremap <F5> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
:nmap <F3> :vimgrep //j ** <bar> copen
```

If more information is needed to solve these problems, I'll gladly provide it.

**UPDATE:** I solved the first two problems by putting 'set t_Co=256' in my .vimrc, but the upper bar is still the same is it normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the first two problems by putting the `set t_Co=256` in my .vimrc and solved the missing upper bar problem by putting this in my .vimrc.

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
" Show just the filename
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':t'
```

Comment: You shouldn't set `t_Co=256`. Instead, set `TERM=xterm-256color` (or if using `screen`/`tmux`, `TERM=screen-256color`) in your shell initialization files.

Comment: The contributor said: "vim should detect this value automatically, but only if you have your terminal set up properly". Setting your terminal up properly is having `TERM=xterm-256color`. Having done that, Vim will detect that `t_Co` should be 256. It's if you have `TERM` supporting 256 colors and Vim doesn't detect it that you have to use this override.

Comment: @muru Will try that, but why shouldn't I set it as it is suggested [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim) to enable 256 colors in Vim?